# Use of blade component in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm looking to use the component blade feature:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots

unfortunately, my framework version is 5.3, could I use it somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade your Laravel version?

Comment: Can't using PHP 7.0 and getting a lot of errors when trying to upgrade

Comment: Have you tried it here? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade